# Merge several Series with different indexes, summing over duplicated indexes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Suppose I have three Series

```
s1 = pd.Series(data=np.arange(5))
s2 = pd.Series(data=np.arange(5),index=np.arange(2,7))
s3 = pd.Series(data=np.arange(5),index=np.arange(5,10))
```

Which is the most efficient method to merge them into a series which sums `data` values in duplicated indexes, and keeps values in non-duplicated indexes. In other words, for `s1`, `s2`, `s3` we would expect the output:

```
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    4
4    6
5    3
6    5
7    2
8    3
9    4
```

In reality we could have a large number of series with a large number of data entries so looping is not efficient.

Comment: Would all indexes of the series be in ascending order and would they be all positive?

Comment: Not necessarily, they may also be label type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's use `concat` and `sum` here:

```
pd.concat([s1, s2, s3]).sum(level=0)

0    0
1    1
2    2
3    4
4    6
5    3
6    5
7    2
8    3
9    4
dtype: int64
```

Concatenation is an O(n) operation (linear complexity), recommended 99% of the time.

---

If you like method chaining, this one's for you.

```
s1.append(s2).append(s3).sum(level=0)

0    0
1    1
2    2
3    4
4    6
5    3
6    5
7    2
8    3
9    4
dtype: int64
```

Not recommended for more than 3 series. Appending two at a time turns out to be quadratic in complexity.

Comment: Nice - I guess `concat` is dealing with the outer join under the hood.

Comment: @ojlm This is technically not a Join operation as you are only concating vertically. the `join` argument would make a difference when merging them horizontally. Here's an exhaustive discussion on the topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101

Answer (score 3):

Here's one with NumPy tools -

```
def sum_series(L): # L is list of series
    aL = [list(l.index) for l in L]
    intL,unqL = pd.factorize(np.concatenate(aL))
    sums = np.bincount(intL,np.concatenate(L))
    return pd.Series(sums, index=unqL)
```

Sample run -

```
In [158]: L = [s1,s2,s3] # list of series

In [159]: sum_series(L)
Out[159]: 
0    0.0
1    1.0
2    2.0
3    4.0
4    6.0
5    3.0
6    5.0
7    2.0
8    3.0
9    4.0
dtype: float64
```

With generic labels -

```
In [170]: L
Out[170]: 
[Label0    0
 Label1    1
 Label2    2
 Label3    3
 Label4    4
 dtype: int64, Label2    0
 Label3    1
 Label4    2
 Label5    3
 Label6    4
 dtype: int64, Label5    0
 Label6    1
 Label7    2
 Label8    3
 Label9    4
 dtype: int64]

In [171]: sum_series(L)
Out[171]: 
Label0    0.0
Label1    1.0
Label2    2.0
Label3    4.0
Label4    6.0
Label5    3.0
Label6    5.0
Label7    2.0
Label8    3.0
Label9    4.0
dtype: float64
```

**Version #2**

Using a concatenation on the array data and employing smart output dtype, probably a more desirable output could be obtained with something like this -

```
def sum_series_v2(L): # L is list of series
    aL = [list(l.index) for l in L]
    v = [l.values for l in L]
    intL,unqL = pd.factorize(np.concatenate(aL))
    sums = np.bincount(intL,np.concatenate(v))
    dtype = np.result_type(*[l.dtype for l in L])
    return pd.Series(sums.astype(dtype), index=unqL)
```

Sample run -

```
In [225]: sum_series_v2(L)
Out[225]: 
Label0    0
Label1    1
Label2    2
Label3    4
Label4    6
Label5    3
Label6    5
Label7    2
Label8    3
Label9    4
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Nice alternative method